# Access to Dynamic object properties by name

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic

I have created this dynamic object, and I want to access the properties by name:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
obj.Name = "Reza";
```

What I want is

```
obj["Name"] = "Reza";
```

or

```
var name = obj["Name"];
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `ExapnadoObject` or `ExpandoObject` ?

Comment: Simply cast it as `IDictionary<string, object>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the definition of [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ```
> public sealed class ExpandoObject : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, 
> IDictionary<string, object>, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, object>>, 
> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>, IEnumerable, INotifyPropertyChanged
> ```

As you can see, one of the interfaces implemented by the class is `IDictionary<string, object>`. Therefore, you could do this:

```
var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>)obj;
dict["Name"] = "Reza";
var name = dict["Name"] as string;
```

Note that if all you need is behavior where you access elements the dictionary-style, using `ExpandoObject` is not necessary; a plain `Dictionary<string,object>` would do just fine.

Comment: I wonder why IDictionary was implemented explicitly. The calling would have been cleaner without that.

Answer (score 3):

`ExpandoObject` implements `IDictionary<string, object>` which allows you to do something like this:

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();

IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = obj;

dictionary["Name"] = "Reza";

var name = dictionary["Name"];
```

Comment: Although your answer is right too but dasblinkenlight was more descriptive and I up vote yours and accept that ;)

Answer (score 3):

`TryGetValue` is so handy provided by `IDictionary`

```
dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
IDictionary<string, object> dictionary = obj;
dictionary["Name"] = "Reza";
dict.TryGetValue("Name", out object name);
```